# 14.04 - Mac Mini - wireless connects but no Internet

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, mac

I was able to install 14.04 on a Mac Mini pretty easily.  However, (and I have searched for answers, here and other sources), the behavior is as follows:

1)  Able to connect to Internet via Ethernet

2)  Wireless networks show up and I am able to connect, but no Internet connectivity over the connection, not able to browse or ping etc.

One thing I have not tried, is turning on encryption of the wifi, but the Mac is connecting solidly to the network over Ubuntu... so it is odd.

The Mac connects to the same network without issues when running OSX, as do other devices.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Here are ifconfig and route output:

```
jg@jg-Macmini:~$ ifconfig



eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:4b:bd:03:58  
           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
           RX packets:275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
           RX bytes:20497 (20.4 KB)  TX bytes:20497 (20.4 KB)

 wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:00:f8:b7:45  
           inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::225:ff:fef8:b745/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:3995
           TX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:8626 (8.6 KB)
           Interrupt:19
```

jg@jg-Macmini:~$ route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.42.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Thanks

Comment: can you provide information about the network connection, e.g. output of `ifconfig` and `route`. - Are you able to ping your router?

Comment: output inserted above.

Comment: well that looks like you are not at all connected to the router, or your wifi interface serves as the router. You might want to change that in your _NetworkManager_

Answer (score 2):

**You do not have a default gateway assigned.**

Here is my routing info

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    2      0        0 wlan0
```

Note that my first line, aside from the different address, is just like yours.
It says that the other computers that start with 192.168.0 are on the wlan0 interface.
BUT if the IP doesn't match ANYTHING use the 0.0.0.0 line, and use 192.168.0.1 as a gateway to get to another network (Internet)

Fixing this would depend on how you are getting your networking information.  If it's through DHCP, then the router isn't generating the right gateway.  If you are using static information (You chose the address arbitrarily) then you need to add the default gateway.